# json_decode corrupts my JSON object

Tags: php

I have sent a JSON object to PHP to query my database and return a resultset, however I am getting some unusual behaviour - my JSON object arrives in my script as:

```
{ "username": "Bobby", "dob": "2015-02-12T00:00:00.000Z" }
```

Which looks fine too me, in order to perform operations on that data I know I need to use `json_decode` so that PHP receives it as an array, however when I perform `json_decode($request)` the output array is:

```
{ undefined: 24, Bobby: ["dob"]}
```

I have never had this happen before, and can't quite get my head around exactly why this is happening

EDIT: My complete operation looks like:

```
if(isset($request)) {

   var_dump($request);

   $json = json_decode($request, true);

   var_dump($json);

}
```

The first dump is correct, once decoded I get the skewed output

**EDIT:** I am sending the JSON object from Angular, but I don't think this should cause any problems, however its the only thing I have done differently to what I have in previous apps:

```
if (!(userName === undefined) && !(userDob === undefined))
    {
        var json = { "name" : userName, "dob"  : userDob };

        // Create POST request to the file in the url, send it to PHP in JSON format
        var callback = $http.post($scope.url, json );

        callback.success(function(data, status) {
                ...
        });
    }
```

**EDIT** I don't quite understand why, but using `print_f` or `var_dump` was delivering skewed results, however if I simply did:

```
$json = json_decode($request);

$name = $json->name;
$dob  = $json->dob;

echo $name;
echo $dob;
```

It returns the results I would expect.

Comment: Handy tool: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: That is a Javascript object not JSON.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://json.org/). Keys need to be "string".

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo - that still does not resolve the issue

Comment: I would suggest looking at the documentation for [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to help you narrow down exactly what is causing the issue.

Comment: What does var_dump($request) _exactly_ looks like? I suppose you're expecting a string, is it a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may need quotes around the keys:

{ "username": "Bobby", "dob": "2015-02-12T00:00:00.000Z" }

Give that a try.

Comment: I'd thought that too, still getting the same results :(

Comment: $str = '{"username": "Bobby", "dob": "2015-02-12T00:00:00.000Z" }';
print_r(json_decode($str));
This outputs: stdClass Object ( [username] => Bobby [dob] => 2015-02-12T00:00:00.000Z )

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f587bb3a4ff01cea35caa8c800a5363d33071e62

Comment: add true as 2nd parameter to make it an array: json_decode($str, true); [Tested here](http://3v4l.org/Lnmo4)

Comment: I'm already using `true` as a second param, for me the above prints `stdClass Object ([[], [], 2015, 2 {undefined: 24, dasdasd: ["dob"]}]) "2015-01-28T00:00:00:00.000Z" }`

Comment: must be something weird in you result string. Where is it coming from?

Comment: The only thing I have done differently is use AngularJS to send the data, therefore I'm reading it from `file_get_contents`, however my initial `var_dump` is what I'd expect, so I am not sure what is causing it to break..

Answer (score 0):

That's a JavaScript object.  Try:

```
var json = { "name" : userName, "dob"  : userDob };
JSON.stringify(json);
```